# show empty string if property not exist

Tags: php

In the lower versions of php I used to use the following code to show object property in the page :

```
  <input type=text value='<?php echo $obj->title ;?>'>
```

In the edit mode $obj was an object fetched from database and user could see the already existed value,
and for insert mode there was no $obj because there was no $_GET["obj_id"] and $obj wasn't defined so the input field was shown empty ,

In the new versions php stops the insert pages because $obj isn't defined or has no property named title ,
So I should use something like this :

```
<input type=text value='<?php echo isset($obj)?$obj->title:"" ;?>'>
```

Now what I want to do is to make this some shorten, I created a function like the following but it doesn't seem to work and keeps showing the error,

```
function showprop($obj,$prop)
{
if( isset($obj) )
 echo $obj->{$prop};
else
 echo "";
}

<input type=text value='<?php showprop($obj,"title");?>'>
```

Any suggestion to make this work without getting notice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is not going to work, since PHP will try to resolve `$obj` before passing its value into the function, so you're left with the same problem.

Use the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) instead (available from PHP 7):

```
<?= $obj->title ?? '' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because the `$obj` is not defined. But you can pass the variable of the name to the function and check whether the global variable is defined in that function - but this is ugly:

```
function showprop($obj,$prop)
{
    if( isset($_GLOBALS[$obj]) )
        echo $_GLOBALS[$obj]->{$prop};
    else
        echo "";
}

<input type=text value='<?php showprop('obj',"title");?>'>
```